# Pinged by a comment link in chat

Tags: bug, comments, chat, onebox, ping

The other day, someone in chat posted a link to a comment that pinged me. To clarify, the *comment* contained the text `@DJMcMayhem`, but the *chat message* did not. When they posted the chat message, I heard a familiar "ding", and a little red circle appeared on my screen.

You can see this chat message [here in the transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31681573#31681573), although the relevant comments are now deleted.

Surely this is not the intended behavior! What's the point of pinging someone when you did not explicitly type `@username` in chat?

Comment: No repro. The `@username` is indeed red for me, but there is no ping and no little red circle.